# Is there a way to tell ASP.NET app where to look for a static main html

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET WebAPI project and I have an AngularJS front-end in the same project. Right now, I have Index.html in the root of the project, and it works fine: when I enter something like localhost:8080, I can see the contents of my Index.html. However, I'd like to move it to an other folder, out of the root folder. Is there a way to config the application to look for a static startup Html file in a specific location? I'd like to avoid using MVC controllers just to point to the right file (I'd like to keep them out of my app).

I don't have any configuration for MVC in my Global.asax (that is no MVC RouteConfig) because I don't want to use MVC in my application because that's to be taken care of by Angular. Angular gets loaded from my Index.html. I just want to move my Index.html to Angular folder to keep it all in one place.
I am pretty sure there was a way to configure that stuff in web.config in the WebForms days, but I don't remember anything about that.

Comment: You should contain more reliable information about your issue. Have you tried with **RouteConfig** class or **webconfing** file?

Comment: I've edited the question. The thing is, I don't have any RouteConfig in my app because I just want to stay away from MVC. I only have configuration for WebApi.

Comment: This sounds like a candidate for URL Rewriting.

Comment: Why use ASP.NET at all then? Just serve the index.html file using IIS (or whatever web server you want)...

Comment: ASP.NET -> for simplicity. I am using ASP.NET WebApi afterall. All in one place. Not to have to think about other servers. Just hit F5 and I have all I want. Also, to be honest, I don't know how to serve the file using IIS or whatever just like that. Besides, I want the request links to be relative.

Comment: I mean, come on, I already have everything working. All I want is for my ASP.NET application to serve the default static html from a different directory. I am absolutely 100% positive there was an option of even specifying the default file name and extension in WebForms (I just don't remember how). There MUST be the way to do this in current versions of APS.NET.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question. Web.config needs this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <clear/>
        <add value="SomeDir/SomeHtml.html"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
...
```